# Form action URL is different than page URL

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

**Issue**: 
I have a form that has a different form action="url" than the page URL the form resides in.

page URL = www.page.com
form action = "http://www.differentserver.com"

**Problem**:
When posting the form it navigates to the form action URL.

**Question**:
What is the best way to still POST to the action URL but stay on the Form page using jquery/ajax

Also, the action URL post back an xml stating if the lead went through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use AJAX to submit data to another domain.

However you can use an old "hack":

```
<form action="http://www.differentserver.com/" method="post" target="hiddeniframe">
    ...
</form>
<iframe style="display:none" name="hiddeniframe"></iframe>
```

This will submit the form to the other domain, but won't appear to affect the current document.

Answer (score 1):

You can always post it to a hidden Iframe `target='framename'` and hook into the Iframe's ONLOAD event to detect when it is complete.

Answer (score 0):

Redirect after the differentserver.com OR use curl to perform the action

Answer (score 0):

[Jquery does this well](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

Posting the entire form

```
//Jquery Code
$.post("test.php", $("#form_name").serialize(), function(result){
 // return 
 var aa = result;

});
```

Posting specific parts of the form

```
//Jquery Code
 /* get some values from elements on the page: */
 var $form = $( this ),
  term = $form.find( 'input[name="s"]' ).val(),
  url = $form.attr( 'action' );

 /* Send the data using post */
 var posting = $.post( url, { s: term } );

 /* Put the results in a div */
 posting.done(function( data ) {
   var content = $( data ).find( '#content' );
  $( "#result" ).empty().append( content );
   });
```

If you are using a Submit button, this will stop the form from posting normally.

```
 /* stop form from submitting normally */
  event.preventDefault();
```